# python - how to identify page breaks within a docx file, and create list of text within each page

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, nlp, docx

I have the following code to split each paragraph of a docx file and append to a list, but I need to identify the page breaks within the xml tree structure and create a list of text for each page. Happy to provide the exact namespaces if it'd be helpful:

```
xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
tree = XML(xml_content)
aggText = []
#tree.getiterator method looks at previously defined word namespaces
for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
     texts = [node.text
             for node in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT)
             if node.text]
     if texts:
        aggText.append(''.join(texts))
```

I'm imagining that the updated loop will looking something like the below, but am unsure about locating the page break within the xml tree structure:

```
aggText = []
for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
     texts = [node.text
             for node in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT)
             if node.text]
     #page breaks in xml read 'w:lastRenderedPageBreak'
     #below doesn't work, need a way to search raw xml for the page break identifier
     if texts.count(lastRenderedPageBreak) > 0:
        pages = aggText.append(''.join(texts))
        texts = []
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows, I also updated the iterator function as getiterator() is now deprecated.

```
NAMESPACE = 
'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
pages = []
PARA = NAMESPACE + 'p'
TEXT = NAMESPACE + 't'
PAGE = NAMESPACE + 'lastRenderedPageBreak'
aggText = ''
for paragraph in tree.iter(PARA):
     aggText += ''.join([node.text
             for node in paragraph.iter(TEXT)
             if node.text])
     if aggText and [node for node in paragraph.iter(PAGE):
        pages.append(aggText)
        aggText = ''
if aggText != '':
     pages.append(aggText)
```

Comment: what is `NAMESPACE` here? `NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}' ` ?

Comment: That's correct! Should have included it in the answer.

Comment: just do/include it.

Answer (score 0):

Created a Word doc in MS Word 2011 on a Mac.

Word doc saved as Word XML doc is 4 pages with the following content per page:

1. Page 1
2. Page 2
3. *[empty on purpose]*
4. Page 4

The xml that is relevant is as follows:

```
<w:t>Page1</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="7DC7FC1F" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00147F82" w:rsidRDefault="00147F82"><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="7C202865" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00E3126A" w:rsidRDefault="00147F82"><w:r><w:lastRenderedPageBreak/><w:t>Page2</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="78BAA3B3" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00E3126A" w:rsidRDefault="00E3126A"><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="2B26F15B" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00E3126A" w:rsidRDefault="00E3126A"><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p><w:p w14:paraId="1005F61F" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00C66DE3" w:rsidRDefault="00E3126A"><w:r><w:t>Page4</w:t>
```

Between each page is a `<w:br w:type="page"/></w:r>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for checking - but how do I search for that tag within the xml? Is there a namespace that I can reference?

Comment: The above tag only exists on a Mac, and I'm not able to scale saving documents as a Word XML. You have to search for 'w:lastRenderedPageBreak', which I'll show in the answer